# How to deal with custom number format in json schema

Tags: json, jsonschema

I need to define Json schema that will treat '600_00' as a number (60000), using regex works, but the field type becomes string which is not ideal

```
  "numericField": {
    "type": "string",
    "pattern": "^[0-9_]{1,}$"
  }
```

is there a way to keep the type as integer and still support the custom format?

Comment: No, you cannot have a custom formatted integer in json (or indeed any other language I know of)